# Accessing IIS hosted site on other computers via lan

Tags: iis, localhost

I've got a website hosted on my IIS and I would like to access it from other devices connected to same lan. Whilst I can access my local host (default website in IIS) by doing so:

```
http://10.0.1.6/
```

where, that's my internal ip. This always works, even from iPad and iPod.

This has worked fine for all cases until now. Now, I have a website that's hosted in IIS with a binding, `mysite.local` - and I have my host file edited so requests to it would go to IIS.

The trouble is I don't know how to access it on my other devices anymore.

doing `http://10.0.1.6/mysite.local` gives me an error, understandably.
This website works intimately with subdomains so I will have to access it by something like `one.mysite.local` or `two.mysite.local` and so on.

so how do I access this site with other devices? any ideas please?

thanks

I don't know what else I need to provide to come up with an answer, if you need anything, let me know.

Comment: add it to your hosts file on each client you want to test with

Comment: @Jason Hi, I'm sorry, I don't understand that.. can you please expand?

Comment: I mean update the hosts file on clientX to so that "mysite.local" --> 10.0.1.6 - assuming the client you're testing with is a PC/Mac.  If the client is something else - an iPad, etc you would probably need to setup a local DNS server for your network.

Comment: @Jason, aah, I see.. but, the thing is, 10.0.1.6 is not where my site is hosted, should I change my default site to point to that? I guess yes!

Comment: @Jason, your comment actually answered my question, can you post it as an answer so I can accept it, please? thanks! (I was looking for a solution like setting up a local dns, but did not know that was the solution I needed until you mentioned it)

Comment: Ideally there is a way to make the hostname available to all LAN clients without having to change each of the client device's hosts files, I was hoping someone would document it here where the hostname is recognized without having to change the client history file. I remember it documented in some other site, I will go searching!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the hosts file on clientX to so that "mysite.local" --> 10.0.1.6 - assuming the client you're testing with is a PC/Mac. If the client is something else - an iPad, etc you would probably need to setup a local DNS server for your network.

Answer (score -1):

Add two bindings to your website, one for local access and another for LAN access like so:

Open IIS and select your local website (that you want to access from your local network) from the left panel:

> Connections > server (user-pc) > sites > local site

Open **Bindings** on the right panel under **Actions** tab
add these bindings:

1. Local:

   > ```
   > Type: http
   > Ip Address: All Unassigned
   > Port: 80
   > Host name: samplesite.local
   > ```
2. LAN:

   > ```
   > Type: http
   > Ip Address: <Network address of the hosting machine ex. 192.168.0.10>
   > Port: 80
   > Host name: <Leave it blank>
   > ```

Voila, you should be able to access the website from any machine on your local network by using the host's LAN IP address (192.168.0.10 in the above example) as the site url.

**NOTE:**

If you want to access the website from LAN using a host name (like samplesite.local) instead of an ip address, add the host name to the hosts file on the local network machine (The hosts file can be found in **"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"** in windows, or **"/etc/hosts"** in ubuntu):

> 192.168.0.10 samplesite.local